# Is texdistmgr no longer needed on macOS?

Tags: mac, mactex

After a recent update of my MacTeX configuration, I can no longer fond `texdistmgr` (and the symbolic links to it that Homebrew had are reported broken).

Is `texdistmgr` no longer part of MaxTeX; is it no longer needed on macOS?

Comment: The TeX Distribution Preference Pane is no longer included in recent versions of MacTeX since it became too difficult to maintain it over many OS versions. You can use recent versions of TeX Live Utility to change the active TeX distribution.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @HerbS: This means that texdistmgr won’t work anymore as well, right?  At least here (MacOS 10.9.5, TeXLive 2016, all TLs since 2010 installed) I have `texdistmgr` but

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TeX Distribution Preference Pane is no longer included in recent versions of MacTeX since it became too difficult to maintain it over many OS versions. You can use recent versions of TeX Live Utility (TLU) to change the active TeX distribution. Therefore there really isn't a need for using tldistmgr. You can even remove the TeX Distribution Preference Pane which no longer works under Sierra.

The structure used to change the active distribution hasn't changed. I suspect the texdistmgr does nothing more than change which structure is default so it most likely would still work. But given that TLU does the job why use it.

Comment: Did `texdistmgr` ever work? I thought it was a work-in-progress by Jerome to reimplement the guts of the prefpane in Ruby; Bruno reported problems with it long ago. There was also an old `texdist` Perl script by Gerben Wierda, but IIRC it was never updated for x86_64 arch on OS X. Neither is particularly useful now, as far as I know.